# Is it possible to change resolution of an android app programmatically?

Tags: android, performance

I'm developing an application for TV. The media console that I'm using doesn't have necessary resources for handling a big screen and therefore doesn't work smoothly (for instance, animation of `HorizontalGridView` works laggy, and any action in general is laggy). As a possible means for improving the performance could be decreasing the resolution of the screen. For instance, if the TV has the resolution of 1080, I could decrease it to 720. It must have a positive impact on the performance.

Is there any possible solution that would allow me to achieve this?

Comment: Apps do not have resolution. Devices and screens have resolution. I know of no way for an app to change the resolution used by a device for its screen.

Comment: It seems you read only the title of my question. Anyway, I know that it's very unlikely, but maybe someone knows a method to do what I want.

Comment: No, I read the whole question. For example, in your question, you have "As a possible means for improving the performance could be decreasing the resolution of the screen". As I wrote my comment, I know of no way for an app to change the resolution used by a device for its screen. Devices tell the app how much resolution they have, not the other way around.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I understand all that, just wanted to give it a shot.